# Add Directory Service to macOS image

Tags: macos, automator, active-directory, netboot

I'm trying to add an Active Directory service to macOS image. I know how to bind AD on a Mac but I was looking for an automated way to do it for a large deployment 50–100 Macs, **i.e add it in an image profile.** What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you created the image.

If you're using the installer as your source then there's a pane for adding directory servers.

If you're using an installed system as the source then you may have to use something like the dsconfigad command in a script to bind.